# JMeter - Adding a json response from a file and set it as response body in a get request

Tags: testing, jmeter

Im doing some json validating. I need to be able to add a local json file to a response in dummy sampler.
This because i need to validate new json files every day.
I figure out that i might use the JSR223 Post Response to get the file from a folder then set the Sampleresult.setResponseData to JSON.

Is there anyone who have a clue how i fo this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is using [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString), you can put it to the "Response Data" field of the Dummy Sampler and it will read the file from the file system and respond with the file's contents:

[image]

If you have a folder with multiple JSON files and want to read them sequentially or randomly - consider using [Directory Listing Config Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter)